# Are MOSFETS made for specific manufacturers?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, hardware-failure, dell-inspiron

A few days ago my laptop (DELL Inspiron 15 7559) stopped turning on and the charger would turn off when I would plug it in. I took it to a repair shop and they said 4 MOSFETS were dead, but they were only able to replace 3 of them and had trouble finding the fourth one. The missing one is called AO7400A and I can find some generic ones online but none of them says if they are made for Dell or anything. What are the chances that it would still work on my laptop? Are MOSFETS made specifically for specific models or are they standard?

Sending my laptop to an official Dell repair shop is impossible in my country, in case you would suggest that.

Comment: MOSFETs are a common enough part but electrical characteristics vary. So they are not necessarily interchangeable. The shop probably needs to see if they can get the MOSFET from Dell, or if you can purchase a used board on eBay from a known good supplier

Comment: Call or email Digi-Key, see if they can find you one>>>>1-800-344-4539  or  sales@digikey.com

Comment: You can also make a post over here and ask if anyone knows an equivalent to the AO7400A>>>>>>>>>>>>https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll give both of those a shot, thank you.